# Is it possible to implement Hedera Consensus Service in a trust-less manner?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Is it possible to implement Hedera Consensus Service in a trustless manner? Most things that I have seen have messages passing through a centralized server to create the messages for Hedera Consensus Service - we would be looking to continue using our permissioned blockchain (Ethermint) - but would like to use public consensus, too - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One model I've explored (not sure it applies to Ethermint) would be to remove all the mining and p2p exchange of transactions from your private nodes and use Hedera Consensus Service instead. A client of your node would submit a transaction. Your node would submit the transaction to Hedera over Hedera Consensus Service. All the other nodes would receive the message by subscribing to the topic (as would your node).

When a node receives the message, it processes it into the state (e.g., execute contract, etc.). At any given timestamp, all the nodes' states should be identical.

The nodes could deterministically generate blocks of transactions by bundling every n transactions into a block, or create a block every n seconds (as determined by the consensus timestamp of Hedera Consensus Service messages)."